# in.nextLine() disables out.printf(), apparently. bug without error message

Tags: java, eclipse

The following code:

```
    Scanner in;
    in = new Scanner(System.in);
    browseForFile(); //user selects file to read from. Method definetely works.
    System.out.printf("Print me");
    String nextLine = in.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("Argh");
    System.out.printf(nextLine);
    System.out.printf("Common");
```

returns to console:

```
    Print me
```

What's going on?

EDIT: added code to clarify. I'd rather not post the code in it's entirety because of anonymity.

Comment: are you sure there is no error/exception in stacktrace?

Comment: What's `in` ? please post the complete code!

Comment: In case `in` is a `Scanner` (or whatever) on `System.in`, do you actually type something then?

Comment: how sure are you that your program actually terminates and is not stuck waiting for an end of line from the input stream?

Comment: Please address ljgw's point, everything works as normal here.

Comment: You're not under the impression that `in` is reading from that file though; right? Run the code again, when it hangs on `Print me`, type `Hello` and hit enter. What happens then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing `in` is an object that scans your command line, waiting for your input. I've you type something in your eclipse? console, and end with enter, then you will see the rest of the output.

This is not a bug, but rather expected behaviour. The thread which runs the program is waiting for user input.